# Most reliable way of calculating time difference

Tags: java, android, time, accelerometer

I have accelerometer readings that are updated from the onSensorChanged() function each time the accelerometer values change.  I then create a file where I write the accelerometer readings (X,Y,Z) axis on each line but would also like to add the time intervals between each reading.  I was reading somewhere that using System.currentTimeMillis() isn't the way to go.  What would be the best way of doing this as accurately as possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use the [timestamp](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#timestamp) field of a SensorEvent:

```
public long timestamp

Since: API Level 3
The time in nanosecond at which the event happened
```

Just remember the last value and calculate the difference that way

Comment: Calculating the previous and current timestamp is giving me values such as 200012204.  The last 5 timestamp readings are `28194580521720 28194780961176 28194980668203 28195180649892 28195380662101` as you can see the 6th digit always changes to 1,3,5,7 and 9.  I am assuming it is a 20ms difference between each timestamp?

Comment: It varies _very_ widely, depending on the exact architecture you're running on...which is probably phone-dependent, for Android.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Standard Java API call:

```
System.nanoTime
```

Then simply do a difference between times.

Answer (score 1):

[Guava's](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [`Stopwatch`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html) is designed for exactly this use case.

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch().start();
doSomething();
stopwatch.stop(); // optional

long millis = stopwatch.elapsedMillis();

log.info("that took: " + stopwatch); // formatted string like "12.3 ms"
```